# Possible to connect 3 2560x1440 monitors to macBook retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've connected 2 Dell 27" monitors to my retina using the thunderbolt/minidp to dp ports to get their full resolution.

A touch of greed and the need for symmetry has kicked in and I'm desperate to get another until I realised that only the HDMI port was left which doesn't support full 2560x1440.

So, my question is does anyone know how I can achieve what would be an orgasmic setup?

I'm using a Dell U2711 and the Dell U2731.

I was thinking that perhaps my options would be to either somehow daisy chain the monitors or use a thunderbolt/miniDp hub of sorts?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might be out of luck to get the full resolution and not use the HDMI output. My best suggestion would be to run with a [DualHead2Go][1] on one of the MDP ports, but this would render you significantly less than stellar resolution.  Even worse if your monitor can't run 50Hz. [1]: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/#productTabs-2

Comment: I couldn't live without the max res now. I'm thinking a LaCie hub could be the answer but need some more research. No posts online etc of this being a successful setup. Bizarre that noone would